# Can't compile Pango with X support

Tags: compiling, gtk2

I have the goal to compile a gtk version, so I can compile Gimp manually. This is necessary because I use Gimp 2.6, and newer distros only use 2.8 or newer. So I decided to manually compile and old gtk so to be able to compile a gimp 2.6.x.

After an effort that it is even difficult to express in words to be able to compile all the GTK required libraries (with included most of the X library stack), I saw my effort being frustrated by broken compilation attempt with Pango.

GTK requires Pango with X support enabled. And I tried to do so, however, during the make process of Pango compilation (1.8.2 or 1.20.5) with support to X enabled, it generates endless messages like.

For instance with pango 1.20.5 I used these commands before make:

```
./configure --x-libraries=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/X11-1.6.7/lib/ --x-includes=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/X11-1.6.7/include/ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Fontconfig-2.4.0/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Freetype-2.2.1/lib/pkgconfig/:/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.14.6/lib/pkgconfig/ XFT_CFLAGS=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Xft-2.1.12/include/ XFT_LIBS=/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Xft-2.1.12/lib/
```

with apparently worked fine.

However during compilation (make) I received endless error messages. SOme of these

> ../pango/pango-layout.h:253: error: expected declaration specifiers before 'PangoLayoutRun'
>
> /usr/include/_G_config.h:31: error: storage class specified for parameter '_G_fpos64_t'
>   /usr/include/stdio.h:675: error: storage class specified for parameter 'ungetc'
>   ../pango/pango-modules.h:31: error: storage class specified for parameter 'PangoMap'

The error messages are nearly endless. However, the compilation works fine without asking for X and xft support.

The question is.........what can I do? Testing newer pango versions and hoping one works? Trying a newer gtk that might not require Pango with X support enabled?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04...

Answer (score 0):

I hope your efforts to better learn linux build systems will not go to waste.

However, a more reasonable solution would be to use a docker image version of some linux distro which had Gimp 2.6 and run it like this:

http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/

Comment: I don't understand how this link is useful. My distro does not has this docker stuff. Plus there is the performance implications.

Comment: There are no performance implications, docker is not a virtual machine and runs programs at native speed.

Comment: Am I supposed to run this: RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox

# Replace 1000 with your user / group id
RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && \
    mkdir -p /home/developer && \
    echo "developer:x:${uid}:${gid}:Developer,,,:/home/developer:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
    echo "developer:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
    echo "developer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/developer && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/developer && \
    chown ${uid}:${gid} -R /home/developer